# Select panel o select box descuadrado del select

Tags: css, angular, select, scss, angular-material

tengo varios mat-select todos con el mismo panelClass y los mismos estilos.
Sin embargo solo el última me muestra un comportamiento raro, ya que el despegable no se muestra aliñado con su Select padre.
He intentado tocar en clases como cdk-overlay-pane, su id cdk-overlay-0, para tocar en su posición absoluta (aumentando el left), pero sin suceso.
No sé si tiene que ver con algún tipo de display flex o no flex.
Alguien conoce este problema o ya tuvo en el pasado un problema similar?

Muchas gracias
[image: imagen del select descuadrado]

Comment: Hola CBD, beinevnido a la comunidad de SO español, te recomiendo que te leas [ask] y te hagas el [tour] para aprender como funciona aqui el preguntar y responder.
Igualmente te comento ya de primeras que no estaría de más que añadieses código a tu pregunta para que sea más facil el ayudarte y entender lo que intentas explicar.

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude solucionarlo, al final lo que hice ha sido el contenedor de todos los select tener 98% de ancho en vez del 100%, alguna cosa parecía no le gustar de estar a tocar a la derecha en el límite del contenedor. No es la mejor solución, pero ha quitado la mayor parte del desfase del combo del select a respecto de su caja despegable.

(nota: esta página está contenida dentro de una iframe)

Pero no es la solución ideal, en otras páginas pasa lo mismo y no sé como solucionarlo.